# How to retrieve rows from database by passing month in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How to retrieve rows from a SQL Server database by passing month in where condition, as I have used `datetime` datatype for the date column.

Is there any function is SQL Server, where I can send month and will get the row accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table
   WHERE MONTH(datecolumn) = 1
```

this will return all records for January

Comment: Watch out for the table scan!

Answer (score 2):

I would create an indexed computed column based on the month in the date column. This way queries will scale as you'll have a specific column indexed for querying against.

Using Month(yourdatecolumn) = somemonth is going to table scan (as in read every value to determine the month) at query execution time so wouldn't be a good idea for large volumes of data.

See [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1236/avoid-sql-server-functions-in-the-where-clause-for-performance) for a commentary on why using functions in your where clause is bad.

Comment: Thanks for your helping words,I'll keep this thing in mind while doing actual implementation..